# Printing mutiple array list on jsp page in tabular format

Tags: java, jsp, arraylist

I have been trying to print 5 array list on my jsp page using scriplets in tabular format but I am unable to do so. I would be really glad if someone could suggest what's wrong with my code. In my output page, I am just seeing the heading printed. The data in the arraylist is not printed. Also, I am not seeing any error/exception information displayed.

1)view.jsp(My jsp page)

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@page import="com.AppUtils.*"%>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%Utils utils = new Utils(); %>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>View Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="registerForm.jsp">
    <table border="1">
        <tr><td>Cuid</td>
        <td>First Name</td><td>Last Name</td>
        <td>Mobile</td><td>Desk</td></tr>

    <%for(int i=0; i<utils.getCount();i++){%>
        <tr>
            <td><%out.print(utils.getCuid().get(i));%></td>
            <td><%out.print(utils.getFname().get(i));%></td>
            <td><%out.print(utils.getLname().get(i));%></td>
            <td><%out.print(utils.getMobile().get(i));%></td>
            <td><%out.print(utils.getDesk().get(i));%></td>
        </tr>
    <%} %>

    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Register"/>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

---

2)Utils.java(My java class)

```
    package com.AppUtils;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Utils {

    public ArrayList getCuid() {
        return cuid;
    }
    public void setCuid(ArrayList cuid) {
        this.cuid = cuid;
    }
    public ArrayList getFname() {
        return fname;
    }
    public void setFname(ArrayList fname) {
        this.fname = fname;
    }
    public ArrayList getLname() {
        return lname;
    }
    public void setLname(ArrayList lname) {
        this.lname = lname;
    }
    public ArrayList getMobile() {
        return mobile;
    }
    public void setMobile(ArrayList mobile) {
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }
    public ArrayList getDesk() {
        return desk;
    }
    public void setDesk(ArrayList desk) {
        this.desk = desk;
    }
    ArrayList cuid = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList fname = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList lname = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList mobile = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList desk = new ArrayList();
    int count;
    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }
    public void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }


}
```

---

3)ViewServlet.java(servlet where I added the values to all 5 arraylists)

```
import java.io.*;
import com.AppUtils.*;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.util.ArrayList;


/**
 * Servlet implementation class ViewServlet
 */
public class ViewServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doPost(request,response);
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{
        System.out.println("Logining in..");
        // retrieving values entered in form
        String uname = (String)request.getParameter("uname");
        String pwd = (String) request.getParameter("pwd");

        if (uname.equals("admin") && pwd.equals("admin")) {

            try {
                viewDetails();
                System.out.println("Redirecting to view page..");
                response.sendRedirect("view.jsp");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace(); 
            }
        } 
            }

    public void viewDetails() throws Exception{
        System.out.println("Reading Data..");
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("H:/Workspace/teamRecordsApp/WebContent/records.txt"));
        String record;
        String[] split =new String[5];

        ArrayList cuid = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList fname = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList lname = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList mobile = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList desk = new ArrayList();
        int count = 0;
        while((record=input.readLine()) != null){
            split = record.split(",");
            System.out.println("Record is : "+split[0]+","+split[1]+","+split[2]+","+split[3]+","+split[4]);
            cuid.add(split[0]);
            fname.add(split[1]);
            lname.add(split[2]);
            mobile.add(split[3]);
            desk.add(split[4]);
            count = count+1;

        }
        input.close();
        System.out.println("Reading Done...");
        Utils utils = new Utils();
        utils.setCuid(cuid);
        utils.setFname(fname);
        utils.setLname(lname);
        utils.setMobile(mobile);
        utils.setDesk(desk);
        utils.setCount(count);
        System.out.println("Total records : "+count);


    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by _unable to do so_?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis : I edited my post to include answer to your reply :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple things wrong with this.

Your servlet is not actually passing anything to your JSP.  Your `viewDetails` method is constructing an instance of the `Utils` object but that instance just disappears at the end of the method.  Somehow you need to stick it in request scope (`request.setAttribute("utils", utils)`)

Even if you do that, `response.sendRedirect` to your JSP is generating a whole new request, round-trip from the browser, which would lose any request-scoped attributes.  You probably want to forward rather than redirect.

Finally, your JSP is currently getting a new, empty instance of `Utils` - that should be replaced with `request.getAttribute("utils")` that you set from your servlet.

Comment: I was able to implement this.Thank you so much!:)

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues

1. You are not forwarding to the JSP, you are sending a redirect with `response.sendRedirect("view.jsp")`. This will send a 302 response to the http client, possibly a browser, which will then send a **new** http request to `view.jsp`. As such, any attributes you set in the request will not be available in the new request.
2. In your `jsp`, you declare `<%Utils utils = new Utils(); %>`. When you then try to iterate with `utils.getCount()`, you are referring to this newly created object, not the object you declared locally in the `viewDetails()` method. As such, `utils.getCount()` returns `0` and your loop doesn't do anything.

Look into `HttpServletRequest#setAttribute(String, Object)` if you are going to use `RequestDispatcher#forward()` or `HttpSession#setAttribute(String, Object)` if you are going to use `HttpServletResponse#sendRedirect(String)`.